# Hard Reset on SAMSUNG TAB 4 SM T230NU not working. What are the alternatives?

Tags: samsung, hard-reset

I have a SAMSUNG TAB 4 SM T230NU. Don't remember the password. I tried the Hard Reset of

1) Menu(Home) + Power + Volume Up buttons

2)  Power + Volume Up buttons

Each time I try one of the above sequence, I see that the system powers on and I see the initial samsung logo with the model name. After a few seconds, the screen empties and then again, the same samsung logo with the model name. This sequence repeats.

But I never see the RESET Menu.

What did I get wrong ?

Isn't there a way to get a password reset instruction in the email that I've setup ? For example, how do I get to a "Forgot password" screen/button ?

Thank you

Comment: It's not clear if you performed reset as [detailed](https://www.hardreset.info/devices/samsung/samsung-t230-galaxy-tab-4-70/)

Comment: yes, I did as detailed!

Comment: That's not the problem then. Hope Samsung users can help out. All the best